# How to add audio in desktop capture in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

I have added audio to chrome extension on screen cast of desktop. But audio is not in good quality. As, I record screen of the tab. I got good quality video and audio. How can I get good quality audio in desktop recording. Here is what I am using

```
 chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'window', 'audio'], function (streamId) {
        if (streamId) {
              var obj = {
               audio: {
                mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
                    }
               },
               video: {
                optional: [],
                   mandatory: {
                      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                      chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                      maxWidth: 2560,
                      maxHeight: 1440
                   }
               }
            };

            countdownRun(function () {
                window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(obj).then(function(stream) {
    $streamVideo = stream;
    $timeStart = Date.now();
    var audio = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    var video = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    alert(JSON.stringify(audio))
    alert(JSON.stringify(video))
    if (micSound) {
        window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function (s) {
            $streamAudio = s;
            audio = s.getAudioTracks()[0];
            captureUseNacl(audio, video);
        }, function (e) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url: 'mic.html'});
        })
    } else {
        captureUseNacl(audio, video);

        (function () {
            var v = document.createElement('video');
            document.body.appendChild(v);
            v.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
            v.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
                console.log('play video');
            }, false);
            v.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            $streamElement = v;
        })()
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
alert(err)
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
});;
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by removing document.createElement and createObject part. It nothing but adding nose to the recording. If you check on the readystate of audio it is end. It should be live. Again, add `maxFrameRate` to video section to synchronize audio and video. Here is your code

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen', 'window', 'audio'], function (streamId) {
        if (streamId) {

              var obj = {
               audio: {
                mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
                    }
               },
               video: {
                optional: [],
                   mandatory: {
                      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                      chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                      maxWidth: 2560,
                      maxHeight: 1440,
                      maxFrameRate:30
                   }
               }
            };

            countdownRun(function () {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(obj).then(function(stream) {
    $streamVideo = stream;
    $timeStart = Date.now();
    var audio = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    var video = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    console.log(stream);
    if (micSound) {
        window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function (s) {
            $streamAudio = s;
            audio = s.getAudioTracks()[0];
            captureUseNacl(audio, video);
        }, function (e) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url: 'mic.html'});
        })
    } else {
        captureUseNacl(audio, video);
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
 console.log(err)
});
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved a day. Cannot find anywhere how to write correctly constraints for audio